# merging attributes between recipes in a wrapper cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, berkshelf

I'm trying to create a site specific wrapper cookbook for `logstash` with somewhat mixable property.

How `logstash` cookbook works is that you have a `default[:logstash][:agent][:inputs]` attribute, and it's used by a template generate a config file.

So, I had a `base` role, that defined some `inputs`, and a `python_service` role that defined other inputs, and a `node` that has both roles, all these `inputs` would merge and a configuration with all inputs would generate.

I'm trying to achieve the same using `recipes`.

I've created a `work-logstash` cookbook, and it has `work-logstash::base` recipe and `work-logstash::python_service` recipe. a recipe basically looks like this, only with different settings (and other specifics):

```
include_recipe 'work-logstash::default'

node.default[:logstash][:agent][:inputs] = [
    {
        :udp => {
            :type => "syslog",
            :port => 5544
        }
    }
]
```

Problem when `run_list` is **recipe[work-logstash::base], recipe[work-logstash::python_service]** the last recipe just overrides the `inputs` set instead of it getting merged.

Solution I found is the following:

```
inputs = [
    {
        :udp => {
            :type => "syslog",
            :port => 5544
        }
    }
]


inputs.each do |i|
    node.default[:logstash][:agent][:inputs]  << i
end
```

Simply to `append` the inputs to the default attribute, so each `recipe` runs and appends his inputs, final result has all inputs.

This seems *hackish* and since I'm new to `chef` I'm wondering how would one go about it. The reason I'm moving out of roles is that they aren't versioned and I've read they aren't a good place to keep your attributes.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read about attribute precedence. It's an initially confusing feature of chef but worth learning. It explains why an attribute specified in a role will overwrite a default attribute in a cookbook (See: http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_attributes.html ) Once you're read this I think you'll need to set a "normal" or an "override" attribute in your wrapper cookbook to solve your current problem.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I'm not using roles, it's all in the same cookbook, and it seems that recipes in the same cookbook are 'redefining' the 'inputs' attribute with a new list each time, instead of merging the list as it would have happened if I indeed used roles.